# JavaScript replace() /g modifier replaces the pattern only last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Primary, my message (div) contains two **identical** images with it's binary content inside `src=""` tag. By clicking the button, i have to kick `src=""` attribute from whole message. I made this with `.replace()` method using `/g` modifier, but it replaces the last occurence only.

My pattern is:

```
$("#event-1").html().replace(/<img\s+id="(.+)"\s+class="(.+)"\s+src=".+">/g, "<img id=\"$1\" class=\"$2\">");
// It's easy-just rewrite <img> without src attr
```

Source message is:

```
Hello!
<img id="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="attachImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS">
<img id="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="attachImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS">
```

Should become to:

```
Hello!
<img id="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="attachImg">
<img id="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="attachImg">
```

But i get wrong result:

```
<img id="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="attachImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS">
<img id="Chrysanthemum.jpg" class="attachImg">
```

The only idea why does it happens is too huge source string because of image's src.
Have you any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Don't do this with regex, please. Why not simply remove it with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And why not just

```
$("#event-1 img").removeAttr('src');
```

Comment: All the great things are simple. Ty!

Answer (score 3):

`id` must be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<img class="attachImg Chrysanthemum" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS" />
<img class="attachImg Chrysanthemum" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS" />
```

then you can use **[.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)**:

> Remove an attribute from each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$("#event-1").find('.Chrysanthemum').removeAttr('src');
```

Comment: Primary i tested this with two different IDs. But i wrote about identical images here to make you sure that the pattern is correct. Sorry, my fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `.+` quantifiers non-greedy, to prevent the regexp from spanning the two images.

```
/<img\s+id="(.+?)"\s+class="(.+?)"\s+src=".+?">/g
               ^               ^            ^
```

But I agree with the other answerers who recommend removing the attribute with `removeAttr`.